# Error in Jmeter when running with multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

When i am trying to run a scenario with more than 2 threads, getting below error. It works fine with 1 and 2 threads.

Sampler:
Response code:Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Comment: Pls provide the detailed description like which browser and whether you are running in GUI or non-GUI mode. Ensure you are giving proper proxy details and CA Certificates are accepted

Comment: I am in GUI mode and CA certificate is added to Browser's Trusted root certification Authorities. Browser : User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko is mentioned in the header manager of the http request